# jQuery - countTo plugin works locally but not on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I have the below code work just fine locally but when uploaded to a shared hosting, it is stopping on some random numbers.

It works fine on clicking 'restart' button. But I want the count to run the first time when the page loads.

Here is the link where my code is hosted:
https://spoose.com/others/test/

Link to the plugin code:
https://spoose.com/others/test/countto.js

```js
$(function() {
  let the_timer = $('.timer').countTo();
  $('#restart').on('click', function() {
    the_timer.countTo('restart');
  });
});
```

```html
<p class="timer" data-from="0" data-to="10000" data-speed="10000" data-refresh-interval="50"></p>
<button id="restart">restart</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://spoose.com/others/test/countto.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. It seems to work as expected

Comment: Hi, did you check the link i provided? https://spoose.com/others/test/

Comment: Works there too. Perhaps you need to refresh your browser?

Comment: Your link works fine in FF and IE (10) for me.  Are you getting console errors when it stops randomly?

Comment: @NathanChampion console is clean. I  tried refreshing multiple times but it doesn't work. I also tried opening it in different browser....but same result. I tried in Brave and google chrome.

Comment: I tried the link in firefox and edge. it works fine there. I guess it's some browser cache or some extension messing with my code. but the attached jsfiddle and the local script works fine in same Brave and Google Chrome browsers. This seems weird.

Comment: Are you running behind a corporate firewall? That has been the source of many of the issues like this that I have run into.

Comment: No it's my personal laptop.